# MS Access does not add new Entry

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

So I have created a Table and a Form, which allows you to Save New Record to the table, by entering some fields.

Everything works fine, except that while clicking "Save New Record" button, the new entry **is NOT** saved, but it **Edits** the previous entry!

So no more then 1 record is inside the Primary Table.

Could it be something with Relationships ?

**I have two tables:**

1. PrimaryTable
2. ContactsTable

Both have the same name as Primary Key and are connected via that Key (inside relationships).

If you need more information or some screenshtos, pleaese let me know in comments!

**CODE FOR SAVE NEW RECORD:**

```
Private Sub onSaveBtn_Click()
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
End Sub
```

Thanks,
David

Comment: Can you please post the code which should add the new record?

Comment: Yes, ofcourse. I added it in the Main Question.

Comment: I do need to know what happens in `acCmdSaveRecord`. Alternatively you can also post a SQL-Script if you add the record via SQL.

Comment: What do you mean Alexander with "what happens in asCmdSaveRecord" ?
I just have a button, when you click on it, it fires the even procedure "onSaveBtn_Click()"  - that I copied above in Main question what it does. It should save the new record, but instead, it just edits the first entry.

Comment: Are you using a bound form?

Comment: Im new to Access. I just created a 2 Tables that are connected together via Relationships. Their Primary Keys are connected.
Then with Form Wizard I created my Form.

Comment: I mean what `acCmdSaveRecord` does. You did this command, didn't you? If that's a Access-stock command, then it's probably the wrong one. Because, as the name states, it just saves a record. You want to add a record. I remember, when doing something similar, I incremented the ID by 1 and then saved the record. That way it created a new row on the database. You can also save via SQL, that may be a bit more work, but it will pay off later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you created your form through the wizard it is likely a bound form.  This means that as you edit information in the form you are editing the records directly.  When you open your form if there is already data populated then the command you have included in your button `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord` is going to save the information displayed on the form to whatever record was open.

There are a few ways you can deal with this issue.  At the bottom of your form you may have navigation buttons and one with a * icon beside it.  This indicates create a new record and will clear the form and move it to a blank record when pressed.

You can also add a button on your form with the following code that will do the same thing.
`DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec`

Another option you have is to create an unbound form that will allow you to completely control how your users navigate your data.